# How does the R^2 value of a log plot of y against x compare to a linear plot of ln(y) against x in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

When I plot the following data of **Number of cells** against **Time** and apply the logarithmic function, I obtain a R^2 = 0.8292.

(see here )

[image: 1]

But if I plot **ln(Number of cells)** against **Time** I obtain a different R^2 (= 0.6792), (see here)

[image: 2]

How should this be interpreted? Which R^2 is more accurate?

I have included the relevant data below in markdown format

| Time | Number of cells | ln(cell_number) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 16 | 190 | 5.247024 |
| 17 | 1380 | 7.229839 |
| 20 | 1758 | 7.471932 |
| 24 | 2052 | 7.62657 |
| 27 | 2119 | 7.6587 |
| 46 | 2365 | 7.768533 |
| 49 | 5176 | 8.551788 |
| 51 | 5256 | 8.567126 |
| 53 | 5437 | 8.600983 |
| 80 | 6172 | 8.727778 |
| 81 | 8428 | 9.039315 |
| 98 | 8627 | 9.062652 |
| 106 | 9475 | 9.156412 |
| 107 | 11840 | 9.379239 |
| 119 | 11898 | 9.384126 |
| 120 | 13455 | 9.507106 |
| 121 | 15955 | 9.677528 |
| 137 | 16463 | 9.708871 |
| 156 | 16748 | 9.726034 |
| 164 | 17623 | 9.77696 |
| 168 | 18544 | 9.827902 |
| 172 | 18983 | 9.851299 |
| 180 | 19614 | 9.883999 |
| 184 | 21883 | 9.993465 |
| 187 | 23347 | 10.05822 |
| 189 | 23913 | 10.08218 |
| 190 | 24420 | 10.10316 |
| 194 | 25936 | 10.16339 |
| 202 | 26246 | 10.17527 |
| 204 | 28252 | 10.24892 |
| 206 | 31252 | 10.34984 |
| 215 | 31427 | 10.35542 |
| 241 | 31959 | 10.37221 |
| 243 | 32309 | 10.3831 |
| 245 | 32644 | 10.39342 |
| 251 | 33199 | 10.41028 |
| 264 | 35024 | 10.46379 |
| 277 | 35651 | 10.48153 |
| 278 | 35744 | 10.48414 |
| 286 | 36551 | 10.50646 |
| 323 | 36911 | 10.51626 |
| 325 | 37114 | 10.52175 |
| 340 | 38906 | 10.5689 |
| 347 | 39568 | 10.58578 |
| 366 | 40329 | 10.60483 |
| 374 | 42399 | 10.65488 |
| 384 | 42722 | 10.66247 |
| 389 | 42874 | 10.66602 |
| 401 | 46527 | 10.74779 |
| 421 | 47405 | 10.76648 |
| 431 | 47996 | 10.77887 |
| 446 | 49059 | 10.80078 |
| 449 | 49207 | 10.80379 |
| 453 | 49552 | 10.81078 |
| 456 | 50104 | 10.82186 |
| 476 | 50188 | 10.82353 |
| 500 | 50230 | 10.82437 |
| 505 | 51991 | 10.85883 |
| 545 | 52634 | 10.87112 |
| 555 | 54981 | 10.91474 |
| 557 | 57006 | 10.95091 |
| 575 | 57108 | 10.9527 |
| 591 | 57325 | 10.95649 |
| 603 | 57939 | 10.96715 |
| 604 | 58250 | 10.9725 |
| 606 | 59684 | 10.99682 |
| 609 | 60355 | 11.008 |
| 612 | 63465 | 11.05824 |
| 617 | 63740 | 11.06257 |
| 635 | 65149 | 11.08443 |
| 658 | 66663 | 11.10741 |
| 666 | 67126 | 11.11433 |
| 694 | 67456 | 11.11923 |
| 696 | 68517 | 11.13484 |
| 706 | 68967 | 11.14138 |
| 740 | 71462 | 11.17692 |
| 745 | 74164 | 11.21403 |
| 755 | 76541 | 11.24558 |
| 755 | 77785 | 11.2617 |
| 784 | 82253 | 11.31756 |
| 794 | 84480 | 11.34427 |
| 812 | 86256 | 11.36507 |
| 818 | 86791 | 11.37126 |
| 818 | 88244 | 11.38786 |
| 829 | 88332 | 11.38886 |
| 840 | 88986 | 11.39623 |
| 846 | 90670 | 11.41498 |
| 851 | 91804 | 11.42741 |
| 853 | 93388 | 11.44452 |
| 866 | 93809 | 11.44902 |
| 899 | 93819 | 11.44912 |
| 906 | 95044 | 11.4621 |
| 907 | 95217 | 11.46391 |
| 908 | 95742 | 11.46941 |
| 924 | 96371 | 11.47596 |
| 937 | 97666 | 11.48931 |
| 944 | 98277 | 11.49555 |
| 946 | 98818 | 11.50104 |
| 950 | 99894 | 11.51186 |
| 967 | 99923 | 11.51216 |